# Migrating the specification level of Java EE projects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-ee-5

What do we mean when we say "Migrating the specification level of Java EE projects"? Does this actually entail an application rewrite?

Comment: cross-posted at Programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144963/migrating-the-specification-level-of-java-ee-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Java EE specification is backward compatible, so I don't think it requires you to rewrite your application code.

I think it rather means that you're moving from e.g. J2EE 1.4 to Java EE 6, so that you application server will provide additional features which you *can* but *doesn't have to* use.

However, in time, it might be required or acceptable to rewrite some of your application code because it might be cleaner, more maintainable, easier to read, faster, smaller and so on.

Comment: "your application server will provide additional features which you can but doesn't have to use.".. This will result in a rewrite isn't it or are there any services which will be used automatically upon migration without any changes to the code? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I mean that all your services should be still operational. You'll just be using the application server features that you need. If a new version of specification brings new features to the app server - you firstly need to use them in your code, so then you'll need a refactor. But it's just a regular use case - you can't use any new features without rewriting your code. The point is - you don't **need to** do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it means a rewrite.

It probably means that your Java EE project should pass the tests in the [Application Verification Toolkit (AVK)](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/avk/) for the required specification level or version (eg: J2EE 1.4/Java EE 5/Java EE 6)

Comment: Thanks for the AVK link, wasn't aware of it!